# Modificar un dato por su id en base de datos firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase

Necesito a través de `Javascript` enviar información a la base de datos de `Firebase`, la cuál deberá modificar la existente por la nueva información en base a un id o varios identificadores.

¿Alguien que sepa como puedo hacer esto?

lo que tengo hasta el momento es este trozo de código con el cual extraigo todos los datos de la referecia informacionPrincipal y busco la información que necesito en base al id de la ciudad.

```
   var ciudad = $('#ciudad').val();
    var idProvincia = $('#provincia').val();
    var idRegion = $('#region').val();

   infoPrincipal.on("value",function(snapshot){
                        var datos = snapshot.val();
                        console.log(datos);
                        var leng = datos.length;
                        for(var i =0; i< leng; i++){
                            if(datos[i].idCiudad == ciudad){
                                console.log(datos[i]);
                            }

                        }
                    },function(errorObject){
                        console.log(errorObject);
                    })
```

Comment: Vale, tendrás que llamar a un archivo php para que se pueda conectar con la base de datos. ¿Has realizado este paso?

Comment: si lo tengo hecho a traves de javascript, no se com o hacerlo desde php

Comment: Mira este tutorial para tener una idea básica. Usa JQuery pero así puedes ver la idea de cómo se conectan ambos ficheros.

Comment: cual tutorial??

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8JcQ0yunRds este, perdona.

Comment: aaa pero eso lo domino

Comment: Entonces simplemente tendrás que pasarle el id desde Javascript a php y despues realizar la conexión a la base de datos en ese fichero php

Comment: pasar la varible a php  no hay drama, ahora como hago la conexion desde php a firebase , eso si que no se como se hace

Comment: Mira esta pregunta de stackoverflow en inglés. Yo la verdad que nunca he conectado php con Firebase (siempre ha sido con MySQL) pero mira a ver si te sirve: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28293038/how-does-php-connection-to-firebase-work

Comment: Debes obtener el ref del snapshot "snapshot.ref()" que deseas editar y entonces puedes modificarlo, revisa mi respuesta donde explico un poco mas.

Comment: no pude obtener la referencia

Answer (score 1):

Debes tener en cuenta que Firebase es una base de datos similar a las bases de datos tipo Clave Valor como Redis, por ende la manera en que almacenas la información depende mucho de la manera en que vas a acceder a ella.

Firebase no expone un API para realizar consultas como el lenguaje SQL en bases de datos relacionales, por lo tanto si quieres buscar un dato por ID, debes embeber el ID en el 'Key' o ruta (path) del objeto.

Entonces si quieres acceder por ejemplo a clientes por región, por provincia y por ciudad debes crear 3 estructuras de datos.

```
FIREBASE.child('clientes').child('provincia').child(idProvincia).on("value", loadedByProvinciaCallback);
FIREBASE.child('clientes').child('ciudad').child(idCiudad).on("value", loadedByCiudadCallback);
FIREBASE.child('clientes').child('region').child(idRegion).on("value", loadedByRegionCallback);
```

Aquí nota que utilizo un child raíz llamado 'clientes' dentro de este child creo 3 childs que para mi forma de acceder a la información me sirven como 3 contextos dentro 'cliente', un contexto para provincia, uno para ciudad y otro para región, de esta manera defino mi forma de acceder a la informacioón.

Tu dirás que esto rompe principios al duplicar información, y esto esta bien esto no es una base de datos relacional es una base de datos NoSQL y lo mas importante en Firebase es que es una base de datos en tiempo real, realizar este tipo de bases de datos en tiempo real y escalables como Firebase son complejas, ahora puedes utilizar transacciones al momento de agreagr un nuevo cliente en tu base de datos para agregarlo en los 3 contextos (region, provincia, ciudad) de esta forma aseguras que la información sea consistente.

En tu caso estas realizando una búsqueda lineal dentro de un array almacenado en un ref de Firebase, debes tomar en cuenta que este tipo de búsqueda tiene un pésimo rendimiento así que si el array es muy grande entonces vas a tener un grave problema de latencia.

En fin, una vez que has encontrado el snapshot según tu criterio de búsqueda, debes obtener la referencia de este para poder modificarlo, el snapshot proporciona la funcion snapshot.ref(), que te devuelve la referencia a dicho snapshot.

```
function(snapshot){
    var datos = snapshot.val();

    for(var i =0; i< datos.length; i++){
        if(datos[i].idCiudad == ciudad){ // aqui filtras el snapshot a editar
            console.log(datos[i]);
            var refModifcar = snapshot.ref(); // obtienes el ref del snapshot a editar

            refModifcar.set({...}); // aqui editas el snapshot
        }
    }
}
```

Documentación de Firebase sobre como manipular la informacioón.

[Firebase read and write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write)

Comment: entiendo, muy bien, creo que estoy tan acostumbrado a las base de datos relacionales, creo que tendre que aprender o buscar algo en la nube pero como mysql, gracias por la ayuda